# Регулярные выражения Python исключение слов в кавычках

Tags: python

Дано код:

```
a=int(input("Число:")
print('Число:')
```

Помогите написать шаблон для возврата всех символов кроме тех которые внутри "", ''

Comment: Эта задача НЕ решается средствами регулярных выражений. Дело в том. что RE не поддерживают такое понятие, как **парность**. А в постановке задачи явно намекается на **парные** кавычки/апострофы. Простейший пример: aaa"bbb\"ccc"ddd.  Или такой: aaa"bbb'ccc"ddd'eee.

Comment: Тогда какие пути решение предлагаете?

Comment: представляйте пример входных и выходных, так вам быстрее ответят

Comment: @Anonymous *какие пути решение предлагаете?* в Linux существует иерархия средств синтаксического анализа. Самый низкий уровень - регулярные выражения. Уровень повыше - *awk*. Там уже можно заводить переменные и анализировать парность. ну и верхний уровень - *lex/yacc* (по современному - *flex/bizon*) - для полноценного синтаксического анализа.